# Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ example

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

> We have to evaluate the limit of a sequence $\{f_n\}$ which is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$$ using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. The hint is: $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\pi$.

My solution so far: I was looking for a dominating function $g$ and searched this forum as well to find $$|f_n|=\Big|\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x^2)}\Big|\leq \Big|\frac{1}{1+x^2}\Big|.$$  But now I don't know how to take the next step, I would like to show the conclusion of LDCT i.e $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n = \int f$.

Comment: Editing mistake

Comment: you can switch limit and integral, and the limit is $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=...$

Comment: the limit is just $\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f_{n}|\leq \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ and $$\int_{\Bbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,d\lambda=\pi<\infty$$ (evaluate using $\arctan$).

Thus all the conditions for DCT are satisfied and hence you can switch the order of limit and integration .

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f_{n}\,d\lambda =\int_{\Bbb{R}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{x}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+x^{2})}\bigg)\,d\lambda=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,d\lambda=\pi$$

Comment: Great answer. Thank you

Comment: You can mark as answer then

Comment: I can't put +1 too low reputation, but I clicked what I could

Comment: That's allright. It is advisable to mark as answer inorder to not leave it as an unanswered question.